# display numbers in following order using "For Loop"

Tags: c++, for-loop

a program that display the following output using "For Loop":
2      4       8       16      32      64      128      256      512     1024

```
  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n ;
    for(n=1;n<=2048;n++){
      n=n*2;
    cout<<"\t"<<n<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

]
```

Comment: One line for **For Loop**! `for(int n=2;n<=2048;n<<=1)  cout<<n<<endl;` **Note** `n<<=1` is same as `n*=2` or `n=n*2`. Read more about [Shift Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the `n++` in the for loop, `n` is incremented each iteration.  Additionally, it is multiplied by 2 at the beginning of each iteration.  What you need to do is either change the increment statement in the for loop to transform `n` how you want:

```
for (n = 2; n <= 1024; n *= 2) {
    cout << "\t" << n << endl;
}
```

or use a separate loop variable to perform a set number of iterations:

```
int n = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    n *= 2;
    cout << "\t" << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: separated loop is not working it is display the greater number than 1024

Comment: This seems to work for me:

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        n *= 2;
        cout << "\t" << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

use pow function of c++

```
#include <math.h>
int s=1;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
  s=Math.pow(2, i);
  cout<<s<<"\n";
}
```

also include math header library

Comment: the use of `pow()` is completely overkill for this

Comment: Please, include the definition of Math.pow, if it's a custom function you wrote to efficiently deal with integer arguments. If you meant std::pow, I'm afraid that's not the way to call it nor it's a good idea to use it for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

As jcarpenter pointed out, your mistake is incrementing `n` in your `for`-loop in addition to `n=n*2` (which can be written as `n *= 2` BTW). So I've cutted the increment and moved the double operation to the loops head. Fortunatly, multiplying a number with `2` can be implemented very effiecently with a shift operation. So that's the code I would suggest:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    for(int n = 2; n <= 1024; n <<= 1)
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this piece of code does and why it works as a solution for the OP. And why is OPs code not working? This could be a nice answer if it has a bit more text.